# TensorFlow import error: no module named _pywrap_tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to set up TensorFlow on Mac following the [TensorFlow install docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation).

However after completing the outlined steps and trying "`import tensorflow as tf`", I'm getting the following error trace:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

I have already installed and used TensorFlow on my machine before and never encountered this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part looks wrong:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
```

It uses `pywrap_tensorflow` from Python installation at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` but `importlib` from the one at `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9`.

There must be something wrong with your Python package search path. See e.g. [Keras import error Nadam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809686/keras-import-error-nadam/39250535#39250535) for troubleshooting tips.