# ipython recognizes python module, but jupyter notebook does not

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

On linux I am managing Python via `anaconda`. However, as there was no good support for `amplpy`, I installed that via `pip`.

Now, When I am in ipython, I can do

```
In [1]: import amplpy
In [3]: amplpy
Out[3]: <module 'amplpy' from '/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amplpy/__init__.py'>
```

and similarly if I run from bare `python`. However, when I start  `jupyter notebook`

```
(myenv3) x:yy$ jupyter notebook
```

and open a fresh `python 3` sheet, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-93ba964328c9> in <module>()
----> 1 import amplpy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amplpy'
```

`sys.path` gives me

```
['',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
 '/home/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/x/.ipython']
```

Which is the wrong folder! `ipython` has `/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/...` as path!

What can cause such inconsistency, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Yes, I am certain

Comment: If you use `conda install jupyter` to install jupyter, you can choose which kernel to use. Check menu `Kernel->Change kernel`. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Sraw Should there be a "Kernel" menu inside Jupyter notebook? I have none. But when I am creating a new notebook, I can choose between `python3` and `julia`, and I am choosing the former.

Comment: You should find a "Kernel" menu when you are editing a notebook. But it seems not the point... Could you check `sys.path` in notebook?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras import error Nadam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809686/keras-import-error-nadam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you've installed the module to a different environment than the one your `jupyter` command is using (e.g. if there' no `jupyter` in your "myenv3", whatever else is found on the `PATH` will be used). See e.g. [Keras import error Nadam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809686/keras-import-error-nadam/39250535#39250535) for troubleshooting tips.