# Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm creating a startproject and I'm trying to migrate default django schema using the command line:

```
manage.py migrate
```

The result is: `"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"`

I'm using a virtual environment and I have the next dependencies installed:

```
Django==2.1.2
psycopg2==2.7.5
pytz==2018.5
```

Of course, I'm trying to migrate with the virtual environment activated.

Somebody knows if I've got a problem with the compatibility of the versions? My PostgreSQL is 10.

[pip list command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chyEC.png)

Comment: Can you please share the output of `pip list` command? Also what do you use for virtual environment, is it `virtualenv`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using virtualenv

Comment: I don't think it's about PostgreSQL and such. How do you run `manage.py migrate`? Can you try `python manage.py migrate` while virtualenv is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

**This most likely means that you're not running the command *from within* the activated `virtualenv`:**

```
C:\> my_venv\Scripts\activate

(my_venv) C:\>  (type your command now)
```

---

The error message you're getting is produced [if unable to import `django.core.management`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/manage.py-tpl#L11):

```
try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
```

You can get into the Python console with the same environment as the faulty command (e.g. in your case, type `python` in the same console window) and try to import that module by hand, then [diagnose the resulting import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809686/keras-import-error-nadam/39250535#39250535).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. I ran manage.py runserver in Windows command prompt and it didn't work but it worked once I typed the same command in the Anaconda prompt. So, can I think that Anaconda prompt is a kind of activated virtualenv?

Comment: @Jason Anaconda's prompt activates the `base` Anaconda environment when it's started. Strictly speaking, an Anaconda environment is not a virtualenv (it's not based on the `virtualenv` module but rather uses Anaconda's custom logic), but it works the same way so it can be considered a flavor of virtualenv.